# infinite loop CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression

Am trying to write sql query that has to run infinitely until where condition becomes false.
Tried this query , it returns all rows from tst table (100 rows) and exits

```
with cte1 as
(select 1 as x from tst where flag='N')
select x from cte1 option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
```

But i need the query to coninuously fetch the rows until  condition (Flag = 'N')  becomes false
The Flag will get updated as part of other process, until then the query has to keep on fetching records.

I need to get this done,  only with the help of SQL query

We are running sql server 2014.

Comment: That CTE won't loop at all, it's not recursive.

Comment: For a polling solution you need a loop with a delay in and a check - not a recursive CTE

Comment: What is wrong with a simple query that returns all rows prior to the one where `flag = n`?

Comment: Just to check you're familiar with how Stack Overflow works, is there a reason you have yet to accept any answer or feedback on your previous questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WHILE:

```
DECLARE @StopFlag INT = 0;
WHILE @StopFlag=0
BEGIN
IF something THEN BREAK
END
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/break-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I need to get this done with the help of sql query not with anonymous block